# Memory Match game 6 by 6 Board

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a memory match game in eclipse. I currently have the 4x4 board created and working. How do I create a 6 by 6 board.

Specifically, What should I change the s <= 20 to be for the 6x6

```
 //shuffle the cards
 public static int[][] shuf() {
 int start[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
 int cards[][] = new int[4][4];
 Random ran = new Random();
 int tmp, i;
 for (int s = 0; s <= 20; s++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) //randomize the card placements
    {
        i = ran.nextInt(100000) % 15;
        tmp = start[x];
        start[x] = start[i];
        start[i] = tmp;
    }
 }
 i = 0;

 for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) // put values in cards here
 {
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        cards[r][c] = start[i];
        i = i + 1;
    }
 }
 return cards;

 }
 }
```

Comment: (Doc)Comment and parametrise the code shown.

Comment: What is the purpose of `for (int s = 0; s <= 20; s++)` ?

Comment: Change the `int[4][4]` into `int[6][6]`, and update the loops accordingly? You can just parameterize your method to handle any size...Am I missing something to why this isn't just a simple parameterization?

Comment: @GBlodgett - it looks like that is for shuffling the `start` array

Answer (score 0):

In the code there are several places in which you refer to

- 4x4  (array access) or
- 16 (assignment of  numbers to cards).

Have a look at those and update these, i.e.

- `int cards[][] =  new int[6][6];`
- `for` loops: `r < 6;` and `c < 6;`

To stick to your current approach you also need to increase the size of your `start[]` to `36`.